# use softDelete in backpack and deactive in operations

Tags: laravel-backpack

I use backpack and laravel and I want to see deleted item in show for example...

but because soft delete active a global scope I can't see the deleted item.

I don't know how to deactive scope in some operation for example in show operation that backpack use it for showing an element...

I hope you help me...

I'm using backpack-revision and when I want to see the revisions for a soft deleted item I have that problem too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show them inside the list operation I usually add a filter like this in my `setupListOperation()`:

```php
$this->crud->addFilter(
            [
            'type' => 'simple',
            'name' => 'trashed',
            'label'=> 'Trashed',
            ],
            false,
            function ($values) {
                // if the filter is active
                $this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->onlyTrashed();
            }
        );
```

To show them in other operations it should be possible to something like:

```php
public function setupShowOperation()
{
    $this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->withTrashed();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when I want to use it in show operation it doesn't work.

Comment: is there any way to disable SoftDeletingScope in all revisions route?

Answer (score 0):

In Backpack 5, this was the solution for me:

```
    protected function setupShowOperation()
    {
        $this->setupListOperation();
        $this->crud->set('show.softDeletes', true);
    }
```

This is an undocumented feature, but I found this in the `show()` method of the `ShowOperation` trait.